# Choose largest R subset that any P elements has no intersection

Tags: abstract-algebra, combinations, coding-theory, constraint-programming

Given:

1. A set S of N integers
2. A set T contains some p-integer subsets of S, i.e. some subsets of size p

Goal: 
Find the largest subset H of the set S, where all p-integer subsets of H is not in T.

P/S: It is great to know the size r of H in advance.

For example:

Given:

S = {1,2,3,4,5}

p = 2, T = {{1,2},{1,4},{2,3}}

In context of sets, {1,2} are same to {2,1} and so on.

Then, we have:

H = {1,3,5} because all 2-integer subsets of H {1,3}, {1,5} and {3,5} are not in T

or H = {2,4,5} because {2,4}, {2,5} and {4,5} are not in T

or H = {3,4,5} because {3,4}, {3,5} and {4,5} are not in T

In 3 cases, sizes of H are 3; hence, r = 3.

Comment: can you please re-formulate your question?

Comment: @Kumar thank you, I have already tried re-formulating it. I wish it helps.

Comment: By "p-integer subsets", do you mean subsets of size $p$?

Comment: @PaulSinclair Yes, I mean subsets of size p when saying  "p-integer subsets". I added it to the question.

Comment: The obvious algorithm is first set $H = S$, then choose an element $x \in \bigcup T$ which is maximal for the number of sets in $T$ that contain it. Remove $x$ from $H$, and every set containing $x$ from $T$. Repeat the process until $T$ is empty. I can't guarantee the result $H$ will be the largest possible, though.

Answer (score 1):

You can solve the problem via integer linear programming as follows.  For $i\in S$, let binary decision variable $x_i$ indicate whether $i\in H$.  The problem is to maximize $\sum_i x_i$ subject to linear constraints
$$\sum_{i\in t} x_i \le p-1$$
for all $t\in T$.